# Service Worker in angular 17 not working during offline mode

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, offline-caching, angular-service-worker

**I had installed service worker by this command @angular/pwa and its also registered successfully but on going offline mode it gives no internet connection the data is not being cached and loaded when it goes offline , does any one have solution for same its specifically not working with angular 17**

**App.Module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, isDevMode } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { PostComponent } from './components/post/post.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PostComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
      enabled: isDevMode(),
      // Register the ServiceWorker as soon as the application is stable
      // or after 30 seconds (whichever comes first).
      registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000',
      scope: '/'
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    provideClientHydration()
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>PwaDemo</title>
  <base href="./">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Single+Day&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#1976d2">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

**ngsw-config.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ],
        "urls": [
          "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Single+Day&display=swap"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/media/*.(svg|cur|jpg|jpeg|png|apng|webp|avif|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "dataGroups": [{
    "name"  : "posts",
    "urls": [
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    ],
    "cacheConfig": {
      "maxAge": "6h",
      "maxSize": 5,
      "strategy": "freshness",
      "timeout": "10s"
    }
  }]
}
```

Attached screenshots

[when its online index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwBRO.png)

[when its online /browser page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj6gV.png)

[data doesn't load on offline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tazO9.png)

[network tab while offline on reloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO2CL.png)

[network tab while offline not reloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7buqY.png)